# android room и место на устройстве

Tags: android, база-данных, память, android-room

Нигде не нашел информации по этому поводу: "что случается когда room не хватает места что бы добавить запись в БД"

Comment: `SQLiteDiskIOException` или другое исключение и, естественно, запись не осуществляется.